# Is there a way to extract a "private certificate key" from Chrome and import it into Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

This is a classical Catch-22 situation. I was using online banking the other day under Chrome. I had to order a digital certificate so that I could extend my privileges. The stupid thing is that when I got approved and opened the certificate installation menu, I saw only versions for IE/Firefox available. What the heck, I said, and chose FF - the result I got was Error 202 - ERR:CERT:INVALID. I opened FF, got to the same page, and tried to install the damn thing from there, but got a message basically saying that I must have been given a private key which obviously FF doesn't find.

I read a bit, and it turned out that I really must have been given such a key but only to the browser that I ordered the cert with, i.e. Chrome. The worst thing is that if I deactivate my order, and reissue a new cert, this time from FF, I MUST go to a bank office (!!!WTF), but I am currently studying abroad, so I can't just go back.

Is there a way, that I could extract that key from Chrome's profile, and import it into FF under Windows ? I will be glad to know

Comment: No chance to repeat opening "the certificate installation menu" again, but in Chrome? It's really just some URL, I assume?

Comment: (The thing that the browser needs --and that is currently known to Chrome-- might not *only* be the private key, but also the [certificate signing request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request)?)

Comment: @Arjan: The CSR has already been submitted and signed, and is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome uses the same Windows certificate store as Internet Explorer, so:

a) Try using IE to install your new certificate, then export it from Certificate Manager.

b) Run Certificate Manager and open *Certificate Enrollment Requests* - the private key should be there, although I have no idea *how* to import it to Firefox so that it would accept the issued certificate later.

Comment: is it still the case today updated ```2023```?

Comment: Yes, it still uses the Windows certificate store, although the same situation cannot really occur as Chrome has not supported `<keygen>` for client-side key generation for years.